# Displaying only the last version of an array

Tags: javascript, html

I want to display some data i'm getting from the database and I'm displaying them in an html text field, as such:

```
      for(var i= 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      document.getElementById("f1").innerHTML += array[i]+ "<br>";
      }
```

however, i'm getting repeated results as you might already know that arrays get data like "data_one" "data_one, data two" "data_one, data_two, data_three" (not sure if there is a term for that sort of behavior) and the problem is that the data gets repeated when being displayed as well. I can't get the data first completely and then display the array either because I can't use the Firebase data outside of it's loop.

I know in android you can clear the recycler view adapter, so I was wondering if there is some sort of similar thing in javascript.

Comment: what does the data from your database look like? you can remove the values if you want, it's the keys that are important.. if you do `console.log(array)` ***before*** the `for` loop, what do you see? Unless you are returning just an array of single values, like strings or numbers (eg; `["one", "two", "three", "four"]` or `[1, 2, 3, 4]`), from your database, your code won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do `document.getElementById("f1").innerHTML = ''` before your loop, to clean your view.